# python flask | use html input in different file

Tags: python, html, flask, import

so after I store an HTML input in a python variable using flask. How can I use this variable in a different path file i.e.: [I have commented out the problems next to the corresponding LOC's]

```
/example.html
<input type=text name=inputStr>
<button type=submit>Submit</button>


/main.py
@app.route("/example", methods=['POST'], ['GET'])
def example():
    if request.method=='POST':
        string=request.form["inputStr"]  # suppose this is the variable i'd like to use in a diff file
    return render_template("example.html")


/examplefile.py   
from main import string  # this does not seem to work, as you can see i'd like to import the string here

examplestring = string
print(examplestring)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    /main.py
@app.route("/example", methods=['POST'], ['GET'])
def example():
    if request.method=='POST':
        global string=request.form["inputStr"]  # suppose this is the variable i'd like to use in a diff file
    return render_template("example.html")


/examplefile.py   
from main import example
examplestring = example.string
```

If it doesn't work, this article should help you:

[How to share global variables between files in Python](https://instructobit.com/tutorial/108/How-to-share-global-variables-between-files-in-Python)